# Not getting how to properly close a path in SVG / d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This question is for my Snakes and Ladders game, which I'm writing to learn svg and d3.js.

http://codepen.io/geewhizbang/full/YGWZWv

currently I have some nice snaky snakes instead of the solid thick line I drew before. But I don't know how to get them closed properly.

```
var path = gameBoard.append('path')
    .attr("id", "snake" + snakeIndex)
    .attr("d", cardinalInterpolator(data))
    .attr('stroke-width', 0)
    .attr('fill', 'none');

    hotSpots[snake[0]] = { path: "snake" + snakeIndex, xOffset: 0, yOffset: 0, endPosition: parseInt(snake[snake.length-1]) };

    var pathNode = path.node();

    setSeededRandom(snake);

    var odd = true;
    var dataDown = [];
    var dataUp = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < snake.length - 1; i++) {
        var width = snakeStroke * (10 + (odd ? (1 + getSeededRandom(4)) : getSeededRandom(4))) / 6;
        var point = data[i];

        var tangentPoints = getTangentPoints(pathNode, getClosestPositionInfo(pathNode, point).length, width);
        var rotatedPoints = rotatePoints(tangentPoints.p1, tangentPoints.p2, Math.PI / 2);

        dataDown.push(rotatedPoints.p1);
        dataUp.push(rotatedPoints.p2);
    }
    var lastPoint = data[data.length - 1];
    dataDown.push(lastPoint);
    dataUp.push(lastPoint);
    dataUp.reverse();

    var dDown = cardinalInterpolator(dataDown);
    var dUp = cardinalInterpolator(dataUp);
    var connector = linearInterpolator([dataUp[dataUp.length - 1], dataDown[0]]);
```

The problem is here:

```
    gameBoard.append('path')
        .attr("d", dDown + dUp + connector + "Z")
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('fill', config.snakeColor)
        .attr('stroke', config.snakeOutlineColor);

}
```

The "d" attribute for one of the messed up snakes is:

M154.59472020467123,30.816396077473968Q151.03003730773926,47.616497294108065,147.703857421875,53.25049845377603C142.71458759307862,61.70150019327799,121.74338811238607,79.31515172322591,121.33292134602864,87.15640767415364S140.6673505147298,96.09899927775064,144.9674123128255,105.5255381266276Q147.83412017822263,111.80989735921223,150,150M150,150Q140.52832641601563,116.41847635904949,136.79989115397137,110.04224141438803C131.20723826090497,100.47788899739584,112.20209986368816,95.41289850870768,112.7156473795573,86.23765055338542S135.3200963973999,57.4320287068685,140.22354125976562,48.87392171223959Q143.49250450134278,43.16851704915365,145.40527979532877,29.183603922526032M145.40527979532877,29.183603922526032L154.59472020467123,30.816396077473968Z

Comment: There are no error messages BTW.

Comment: `Z` will perform a `lineTo` from the last point of your path, to the first one. If you want a clean shape, you'll have to make the way back to your starting point using reverted bezier curve.

Comment: I want a line to on the last segment. I can hide the artifact with the last circle I draw on top. I just need how to get the curve to close at the right place.But it draws lines to the base to close the path even with a geometrically accurate line specified as the last element

Comment: Is there an algorithm to convert this shape to Bezier curves?

Comment: I've tried importing the rendered shapes into Inkscape, combining them into a filled shape, but the resulting code is rendered as relative values with lowercase letters for m, and don't even match up at all to the original shapes so I have no clue of what it is doing to connect the shapes.

Comment: Kaiido your answer is about as close to why bother saying anything all as can be. I have two nice paths, and things like Inkscape can connect them so it's obviously possible. But HOW do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that all I had to do was remove the last point of the previous path and then append the next path minus the first letter "M". I also added a final point. The repeated point was a problem when I merely removed the "M" from the second path.

```
.attr("d", dDown.replace(/([0-9\.]*\,[0-9\.]*$)/, "") 
   + dUp.substr(1) + "L" + dataDown[0].x + "," + dataDown[0].y + "Z")
```

I dunno if someone else might have a Q parameter on the the last point and might have to do some more sophisticated regex to catch it. But none of my paths do.